# Can i convert a .XLSX file to a PDF inside my server side event receiver

Tags: 2013, development, event-receivers, pdf, farm-solution

I am working on developing an Event Receiver inside my SharePoint farm 2013. now inside my event receiver i am trying to do the following:-

1. to copy a .xlsx file from a document library.
2. add the file to another document library.
3. convert the .xlsx file inside the destination library to PDF file.

here is my code to move the file from one library to another:-

```
SPDocumentLibrary template = (SPDocumentLibrary)properties.Web.GetList(properties.Web.ServerRelativeUrl + "/Templates/");
SPListItem templetefile = null;

foreach (SPListItem i in template.Items)
{
    if (i.Name.ToLower().Contains("project"))
    {
         templetefile = i;    
    }
}

byte[] fileBytes = templetefile.File.OpenBinary();
string destUrl = properties.Web.ServerRelativeUrl + "/" + projectid.RootFolder.Url +".xlsx";
SPFile destFile = projectid.RootFolder.Files.Add(destUrl, fileBytes, false);
```

but i am not sure if i can convert the .XLSX file to PDF ? is there any available libraries inside sharepoint server-side object module or inside C# which i can include inside my Event Receiver?

Comment: There is nothing in SharePoint that can do this for you. However there are 3rd party products that integrate with SharePoint and even have an API to do this from your event receiver or your workflow environment. Disclaimer I worked on such as product, you can find some details at http://www.muhimbi.com/Products/PDF-Converter-for-SharePoint/summary.aspx